Unitarily simultaneously triangularizable matrices
I don't understand why nobody is talking about simultaneous unitarily triangularizable matrices.
Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB=BA$
For example, I know the classical procedure, in which we prove that the $Ker(A-\lambda I_n)$ is $B$-invariant for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of A, and then we find a vector $u \in Ker(A-\lambda I_n)$ that is a eigenvector for both $A$ and $B$ and then we can work with the basis $\{u,e_2,e_3, \cdots e_n \}$ an then proceed by induction.
I saw this proof: https://planetmath.org/proofthatcommutingmatricesaresimultaneouslytriangularizable
This works for commuting matrices and proves that the matrices are unitarily simultaneously triangularizable, not only simultaneously triangularizable, as a classic proof would do.
My question is:
Is the proof from above correct? If yes, can we apply this on any proof of simultaneous triangularization and get simultaneous unitar triangularization in many other cases such as the case when $\text{rank}(AB-BA) \leq 1$, for example?

do the "classical procedure" $A = ST_AS^{-1}$ and $B=ST_BS^{-1}$ now run QR factorization $QR=S\implies A = Q\big(RT_AR^{-1}\big)Q^* \text{ & }B = Q\big(RT_BR^{-1}\big)Q^*$ now you have simultaneous triangularization by unitary $Q$.  Supposing one understands Gram-Schmidt and the fact that $n\times n$ upper triangular matrices form a ring then this should be close to obvious.

Wow, that is brilliant. But if this is so obvious, why on a lot of websites, including this one, almost no proof of simultaneous triangularization doesn't mention the word "unitar" if it is so easy to prove a stronger result?
I am so shocked, because I think that this unitarity is very important and is highly omited in proofs in which we could easily prove it, just as you said.

I forgot to say that I am very grateful for the fast and on point response and I want to thank you.
